# How Applay Filter to Observable and get the length of list to count notification for each user

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

How Applay Filter to Observable and get the length of list to count notification for each user:
how can I get the count of notification type number for each user by
**html code**

```html
<div class="users-list-body">
  <div>
    <h5>
      {{ onlineusermodel.userName }}
    </h5>
    <p>It seems logical that the</p>
  </div>
  <div class="last-chat-time">
    <small class="text-muted">05 min</small>
    <div class="new-message-count">
      {{ getUserNotification(onlineusermodel) }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**component ts**

```js
getUserNotification(onlineUserModel: OnlineUserModel): Number {
 // var count = this.allNotifications$.subscribe((n) =>
 //   n.filter((u) => u.onlineUserModel == onlineUserModel).length
 // );
 var count = this.store
   .pipe(select(selectDirectNotifications))
   .subscribe(
     (n) => n.filter((u) => u.onlineUserModel == onlineUserModel).length
   );

 return count;
}
```

**Reducer**

```js
const directMessagesReducerInternal = createReducer(
 initialState,
 on(
   directMessagesAction.receivedNotificationForUserAction,
   (state, { payload }) => {
     const directNotification: DirectNotification = {
       onlineUserModel: payload.onlineUserModel,
       notificationModel: payload.notificationModel,
     };
     return {
       ...state,
       allNotifications: [...state.allNotifications, directNotification],
     };
   }
 ),
```

**state**

```js
allNotifications: DirectNotification[];
```

**selector**

```js
export const selectDirectNotifications = createSelector(
 selectDirectMessageStore,
 (state: DirectMessagesState) => state.allNotifications
);
```

**Action**

```js
export const receivedNotificationForUserAction = createAction(
 "[DN] RECEIVED_DIRECT_NOTIFICATION",
 props<{ payload: ReceivedNotificationForUserDto }>()
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not Recommended Way:** You can achieve that by returning the `Observable` instead of subscribing to it from `getUserNotification`, then subscribe to it in the template using the `async` pipe, like the following:

```js
getUserNotification(onlineUserModel: OnlineUserModel): Observable<number> {
  return this.store.pipe(
    select(selectDirectNotifications),
    map((n) => n.filter((u) => u.onlineUserModel == onlineUserModel).length)
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="users-list-body">
  <div>
    <h5>
      {{ onlineusermodel.userName }}
    </h5>
    <p>It seems logical that the</p>
  </div>
  <div class="last-chat-time">
    <small class="text-muted">05 min</small>
    <div class="new-message-count">
      {{ getUserNotification(onlineusermodel) | async }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**However**, it's not recommended to use the functions directly in the component template (HTML file), because Angular will call it on each change detection, which is not preferred from the performance point of view.

Instead, the **recommended** way is to assign the value of `getUserNotification` to an `Observable` once the data is ready and then subscribe to that `Observable` in the component template, like the following:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  // ngOnInit is used here as an example.
  // You can assing the result of `getUserNotification` function each time the `onlineUserModel` has been changed:
  this.userNotificationCount$ = this.getUserNotification(onlineUserModel);
}

getUserNotification(onlineUserModel: OnlineUserModel): Observable<number> {
  return this.store.pipe(
    select(selectDirectNotifications),
    map((n) => n.filter((u) => u.onlineUserModel == onlineUserModel).length)
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="users-list-body">
  <div>
    <h5>
      {{ onlineusermodel.userName }}
    </h5>
    <p>It seems logical that the</p>
  </div>
  <div class="last-chat-time">
    <small class="text-muted">05 min</small>
    <div class="new-message-count">
      {{ userNotificationCount | async }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr amer it works...